# my code get the user name of the IIS hosting machine instead of client machine

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For my .aspx  login concept was to get the logged on user name and logon. my code get the user name of the IIS hosting machine instead of client machine.

```
Dim username As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

Comment: You'd have to configure IIS to use windows authentication, and the user would have to be on the same network as your website.

Comment: Yes, It Works.....

Comment: So, your question is answered?

Comment: yes I have got answer